# Current URL in Safari Extension

Tags: javascript, safari-extension

`safari.application.activeBrowserWindow.activeTab.url` is always `undefined`.

Any idea why this might be?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

My impression is that this happens when the loaded page is not “allowed” in the [Extension Website Access](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/ExtensionPermissions/ExtensionPermissions.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009977-CH8-SW4) section of the extension’s configuration.

> Only the websites you choose have web content injected into them, and only those websites can be manipulated using the `tab` object’s properties, such as `title` and `url`.

Also, it seems that the [Whitelist and Blacklist](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/ExtensionPermissions/ExtensionPermissions.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009977-CH8-SW7) settings are applied “on top of” whatever  is allowed by Extension Website Access.

> First, access is limited by the Extension Website Access settings, then the whitelist and blacklist are applied.

Comment: Aha! You can set your extension's website Access Level to "All" with Extension Builder. Thank you!

Comment: Also, remember to restart the browser for this kind of changes. At least a simple reload didn't work for me.