# safari.application.activeBrowserWindow.activeTab.url is undefined

Tags: safari-extension

I am writing a Safari Extension, to create a duplicate of tab

This is following code i have written so far

```
safari.application.addEventListener("command", commandHandler, false);

function commandHandler(event) {
    console.log("Command Handler");
    if (event.command = "duplicate") {
        var url = safari.application.activeBrowserWindow.activeTab.url;
        console.log("Url " + url);
        console.log(safari.application.activeBrowserWindow.activeTab);
        safari.application.activeBrowserWindow.openTab().url = url;
    }
}
```

and my url is undefined, what is that i am missing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Current URL in Safari Extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8140730/current-url-in-safari-extension)

Answer (score 3):

As suggested above, you might need to change the "Extension Website Access." If you choose "All," you shouldn't need to worry about whitelists/blacklists. If you choose "Some," you must add items to the whitelist otherwise your extension won't be able to access the current page.

If this doesn't appear to work, you might need to restart your browser for the Access settings to kick in... I was having issues with HTTPS pages.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the problem is declare script permissions in Extension editor, it will get `URL` of all desired pages.