# Why doesn't open this code the current website in a new tab?

Tags: html, safari

I want to build a small Safari extension for personal use. I read some tutorials about it and now my first goal is to open the current website in a new tab. The script opens a new tab, but unfortunately it doesn't open the current website.

This is the file *global.html*:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<script>
safari.application.addEventListener("command", performCommand, false);

function performCommand(event) {
    var currentURL = safari.application.activeBrowserWindow.activeTab.url;

    if (event.command == "testExtension") {
        var newTab = safari.application.activeBrowserWindow.openTab();
        newTab.url = currentURL;
    }
}
</script>
```

If I change

```
newTab.url = currentURL;
```

to

```
newTab.url = "www.examplewebsite.com";
```

everything works fine.

So I assume that the variable *currentURL* is the problem.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Have you console.logged currentURL?

Comment: If I try to do that with the command console.log() nothing shows up in the console.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8140730/current-url-in-safari-extension